# Symfony 3.4/doctrine2 : get entity original data in a detached object for comparison purposes

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.4

I'm working on a Symfony 3.4 project and before flushing modification for an entity, I have to compare its old data (original data which are now in the database) with new modification I make before flushing.

So I want to have a detach object which contains my entity with its original data.

## VenteController.php:

```
public fucntion editAction(Request $request, Vente $vente){
        //...
        $originalVente = ????;
        if ( $vente->getMontant() > $originalVente->getMontant() ){
          //trait
        }
        $em->persist($vente);
        $em->flush();
    }
```

Comment: Just do a simple clone.  $originalVente = clone $vente;  Assuming you are not doing anything like lazy loading.

Comment: Can you show all your code?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to compare values in one entity - You can do it by implementing doctrine `preUpdate` [event callback](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/events.html#preupdate) and using functions `hasChangedField($fieldName)`, `getOldValue($fieldName)`, `getNewValue($fieldName)`. In this event you can do whatever you need.

Comment: can I use it with simply annotate a method of my doctrine entity as @ORM\PreUpdate Or I must create an event listener ?

Comment: If you just need to modify some data inside of entity, then you can use anotation (don't forget to add `@HasLifeCycleCallbacks` to entity), if you need to call some external service, then you need to use listener because then you can do construction injection.

Comment: goood! but I get an issue with that please take a look:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51791621/symfony-3-4-field-montant-is-not-a-valid-field-of-the-entity-appbundle-enti