# Symfony 3.4 : Field "montant" is not a valid field of the entity "AppBundle\Entity\Vente" in PreUpdateEventArgs

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.4

I'm working into a Symfony 3.4 Project and I get an issue with @HasLifeCycleCallbacks in function **preUpdate** for my entity Vente.php.

So when I update my entity fields, the die('AA') is not fired and I get this error :

```
Field "montant" is not a valid field of the entity "AppBundle\Entity\Vente" in PreUpdateEventArgs.
```

## Vente.php:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use AppBundle\Validator\Constraints as Assert2;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs;

/**
 * Vente
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="vente")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\VenteRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Vente
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime")
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="montant", type="decimal", precision=10, scale=3)
     */
    private $montant;

//getters and setters

    /**
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
     public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $event)
    {
      if ($event->hasChangedField('montant')) {
        die("AA");
      }
      die('BB'.$event->getNewValue('montant'));
    }
}
```

## Exception:

```
in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Event/PreUpdateEventArgs.php (line 130)
PreUpdateEventArgs->assertValidField('montant') in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Event/PreUpdateEventArgs.php (line 98)
PreUpdateEventArgs->getNewValue('montant') in src/AppBundle/Entity/Vente.php (line 118)

         public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $event)
        {
          if ($event->hasChangedField('montant')) {
            die("AA");
          }
          die('BB'.$event->getNewValue('montant'));


Vente->preUpdate(object(PreUpdateEventArgs)) in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Event/ListenersInvoker.php (line 102)
ListenersInvoker->invoke(object(ClassMetadata), 'preUpdate', object(Vente), object(PreUpdateEventArgs), 6) in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php (line 1060)
UnitOfWork->executeUpdates(object(ClassMetadata)) in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php (line 384)
UnitOfWork->commit(null) in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php (line 356)
EntityManager->flush() in src/AppBundle/Controller/VenteController.php (line 383)
VenteController->editAction(object(Request), object(Vente)) in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php (line 151)
HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), 1) in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php (line 68)
HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), 1, true) in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php (line 202)
Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in web/app_dev.php (line 29)
```

## Stack Trace:

```
InvalidArgumentException:
Field "montant" is not a valid field of the entity "AppBundle\Entity\Vente" in PreUpdateEventArgs.

  at vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Event/PreUpdateEventArgs.php:130
  at Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs->assertValidField('montant')
     (vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Event/PreUpdateEventArgs.php:98)
  at Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs->getNewValue('montant')
     (src/AppBundle/Entity/Vente.php:118)
  at AppBundle\Entity\Vente->preUpdate(object(PreUpdateEventArgs))
     (vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Event/ListenersInvoker.php:102)
  at Doctrine\ORM\Event\ListenersInvoker->invoke(object(ClassMetadata), 'preUpdate', object(Vente), object(PreUpdateEventArgs), 6)
     (vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php:1060)
  at Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->executeUpdates(object(ClassMetadata))
     (vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php:384)
  at Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->commit(null)
     (vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php:356)
  at Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->flush()
     (src/AppBundle/Controller/VenteController.php:383)
  at AppBundle\Controller\VenteController->editAction(object(Request), object(Vente))
     (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:151)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), 1)
     (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:68)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), 1, true)
     (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php:202)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
     (web/app_dev.php:29)
```

Comment: your code works fine with symfony 3.4.14, I have no errors when updating data !

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you have a logical error in your code: you're trying to get the `montant` from `event` if it has not that field (look at the `if`).

Maybe you should modify it as follows?

```
if ($event->hasChangedField('montant')) {
  die('BB'.$event->getNewValue('montant'));
}
die("AA");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code worked in a new project.

```
$vente = (new Vente)
    ->setDate(new \DateTime())
    ->setMontant(10)
;

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$em->persist($vente);
$em->flush();

$vente->setMontant(20);

$em->flush(); //dumps AA
```

Maybe you can solve this by clearing your cache.
Can you send the exception stack?

After @doncallisto answer, I tested his answer and found the error:

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $vente = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Vente')->findOneById(1);

    $vente->setDate(new \DateTime());

    $em->flush(); //Field "montant" is not a valid field of the entity "AppBundle\Entity\Vente" in PreUpdateEventArgs.
```

You can't use $event->getNewValue('montant') without testing if montant is updated.

Comment: I cleared the cache but I still have the error. I updated the post with the exeception trace.

Comment: @DonCallisto answer is right
You can't use $event->getNewValue('montant') if montant is not updated.